# Understanding the CPU Busy Prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am new to Grafana and Prometheus. I have read a lot of documentation and now I"m trying to work backwards by reviewing some existing queries and making sure I understand them

I have downloaded the Node Exporter Full dashboard (https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1860). I have been reviewing the CPU Busy query and I"m a bit confused. I am quoting it below, spaced out so we can see the nested sections better:

[image]

In this query, `job` is `node-exporter` while `instance` is the IP and port of the server. This is my base understanding of the query:
`node_cpu_seconds_total` is a counter of the number of seconds the CPU took at a given sample.

1. Line 5: Get cpu seconds at a given instant, broken down by the individual CPU cores
2. Line 4: Add up all CPU seconds across all cores
3. Line 3: **Why is there an additional count()? Does it do anything?**
4. Line 12: Rate vector - get cpu seconds of when the cpu was idle over the given rate period
5. Line 11: Take a rate to transfer that into the rate of change of cpu seconds (and return an instant vector)
6. Line 10: Sum up all rates, broken down by CPU modes
7. Line 9: Take the single average rate across all CPU mode rates
8. Line 8: Subtract the average rate of change (Line 9) from total CPU seconds (Line 3)
9. Line 16: Multiple by 100 to convert minutes to seconds
   10: Line 18-20: Divide Line 19 by the count of the count of all CPU seconds across all CPUs

My questions are as follows:

- I would have thought that CPU usage would simply be (all non idle cpu usage) / (total cpu usage). I therefore don't understand why take into account rate at all (#6 and #8)
- The numerator here seems to be trying to get all non-idle usage and does so by getting the full sum and subtracting the idle time. But why does one use count and the other sum?
- If we grab cpu seconds by filtering by `mode=idle`, then does adding the `by (mode)` add anything? There is only one mode anyways? My understanding of `by (something)` is more relevant when there are multiple values and we group the values by that category (as we do by `cpu` in this query)
- Lastly, as mentioned in bold above, what is with the double count(), in the numerator and denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these count functions return the amount of CPU cores. If you take them out of this long query and execute, it'll immediately make sense:

```
count by (cpu) (node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="foo:9100"})

# result:
{cpu="0"} 8
{cpu="1"} 8
```

By putting the above into another `count()` function, you will get a value of `2`, because there are just 2 metrics in the dataset. At this point, we can simplify the original query to this:

```
(
  NUM_CPU
  -
  avg(
    sum by(mode) (
      rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",instance="foo:9100"}[1m])
    )
  )
  * 100
)
/ NUM_CPU
```

The rest, however, is somewhat complicated. This:

```
    sum by(mode) (
      rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",instance="foo:9100"}[1m])
    )
```

... is essentially ***the sum of idle time*** of all CPU cores (I'm intentionally skipping the context of time to make it simpler). It's not clear why there is `by (mode)`, since the rate function inside has a filter, which makes it possible for only `idle` mode to appear. With or without `by (mode)` it returns just one value:

```
# with by (mode)
{mode="idle"} 0.99

# without
{} 0.99
```

`avg()` on top of that makes no sense at all. ***I assume***, that the intention was to get the amount of idle time ***per CPU*** (`by (cpu)`, that is). In this case it starts to make sense, although it is still unnecessary complex. Thus, at this point we can simplify the query to this:

```
(NUM_CPU - IDLE_TIME_TOTAL * 100) / NUM_CPU
```

I don't know why it is so complicated, you can get the same result with a simple query like this:

```
100 * (1 - avg(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle", instance="foo:9100"}[1m])))
```

Comment: This was a super helpful description! I plugged in your re-write query and it seems to give the same results, which is great! I did have one question: your final query was: (NUM_CPU - IDLE_TIME_TOTAL * 100) / NUM_CPU. How can you subtract IDLE_TIME_TOTAL from NUM_CPU? They don't seem to have the same units, ones is number of CPUs and othe other is seconds.

Comment: @user1015214 if a CPU spends a whole second doing absolutely nothing, its `node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}` goes up exactly by 1. Similarly, if you have 4 CPU cores, the sum of idle time would be 4 in this case. The more cores you have, the more time the computer can spend on work during 1 second of real time. Sorry, the explanation is probably confusing, somehow I cannot come up with a both short and understandable sentence to describe this. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: That actually does make a lot of sense. I have another question now: In your query, why is there a `rate()`? I understand you need to convert it back to an instant vector once you turned node_cpu_seconds_total into a rate vector, but doesn't rate() mean a measure of change in increase (aka slope of the graph)? Is that what we want for our equation or simply the number of seconds it took? I'd think the later.

Comment: @user1015214 The metric counts how much time a CPU spends in each mode (work, idle, etc). The metric grows by 1 for every second, e.g. a full second in the `idle` mode means that the CPU has 0% load. Now think about it. If the metric goes up by 1 every second, then by calculating a per-second rate we get the percentage of time with respect to the mode and CPU (thanks to the labels). More to that, the square brackets indicate the interval to measure. Without rate and the interval it would have been a flat value of how much time the CPU has spent in each mode since boot.

Comment: @user1015214 The query in human language would go as following: calculate the per-second rate of `node_cpu_seconds_total`, where `mode="idle"` and `instance="foo:9100"` for the last 1 minute. Then calculate the average of the rate result (at this point it is percentage of idle time per CPU), and subtract that average from `1` (100%). Then multiply the result by 100 to make it more human-readable. Oh, and please note that Grafana repeats that query for every datapoint on the graph, so that "for the last 1 minute" is different for each point on the graph.

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the review, as I am the developer of the dashboard, let me update it.